# How to pass multidimensional array from php to .net webservice

Tags: php, .net, web-services, multidimensional-array, nusoap

I've got a .Net web service that I consume with php using nusoap. Everything works great using the following:

```
require_once('libs/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client("mylocation", 'wsdl','','','','');
$PassedVariable = strtolower(trim(["PassedVariable"]));
$params = array(
    "PassedVariable"=>$PassedVariable
);
$result = $client->call('FunctionName', $params, '', '', false, true);
$success = $result["FunctionNameResult"];
$rs = $success["ObjectName"];
$json = '{success:true, data:' . json_encode($rs).'}';
echo $json;
```

with a simple associative array for the $params like:

```
Array
(
    [username] => myuser
    [entereddt] => Thu Apr 23 2015 09:29:03 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)
    [qversion] => 1
    [rversion] => 2
)
```

In the web service, the parameter values are explicitly typed and everything works great.

My problem is that my param array now contains nested arrays like this:

```
Array
(
    [username] => myuser
    [entereddt] => Thu Apr 23 2015 09:29:03 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)
    [qversion] => 1
    [rversion] => 2
    [tickets] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [response] => TRUE
                    [comments] => N/A
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [response] => TRUE
                    [comments] => N/A
                )
        )
    [members] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [member1] => Array
                        (
                            [response] => TRUE
                            [comments] => N/A
                        )
                    [member2] => Array
                        (
                            [response] => TRUE
                            [comments] => N/A
                        )
                    [member4] => Array
                        (
                            [response] => TRUE
                            [comments] => N/A
                        )
                )
        )
    [otherinfo] => N/A
    [summary] => This is a test
)
```

But when this is passed to the .net webservice from the soap call, the argument for "tickets" comes across as a System.XML.XmlNode[]. It doesn't seem to have any contents when evaluated on by the web service. The innertext of the node is simply "Array". How is "tickets" passed from the soap call and how would I access it's contents?